Error “foreach() argument must be of type array|object” in laravel controller
During comments show in the post
Error “foreach() argument must be of type array|object” in laravel controller
The code is as under
Blade File
@foreach($comment->product_images as $image)
 <a href="{{asset($image)}}" class="avatar-md" download="{{basename($image)}}">
      <div class="avatar-title bg-light rounded">
       <img src="{{ asset($image) }}" alt="Product Image" class="product-img avatar-sm" />
        </div>
 </a>
@endforeach

Controller:
public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $comments = Comment::all()->map(function ($comment) {
            $comment->product_images = json_decode(stripslashes($comment->product_images));
            return $comment;
        });

Model:
class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'post_id', 'parent_id', 'post_title' , 'post_category', 'post_description'];
   
    protected $casts = [
        'product_images' => 'array',
    ];
     
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}

How to show multiple images in during comments in post

You have both $casts = [ 'product_images' => 'array' ] and are also running a json_decode on the same. The 2nd operation will probably fail. Also check if the actual data may be null for any of the Comment models.

To check if the $comment->product_images relationship is returning data, you can use die dump i.e. dd($comment->product_images); in the controller before passing it to the view. This will show whether the relationship contains any data or is null. Additionally, it allows you to inspect the structure and content of the data if it exists. Attempting to use foreach over a non-countable or non-iterable item will always return an error.
dd($comment->product_images);

